# Sveltekit routing doesn't work when SSR is disabled

Tags: routes, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I have disabled SSR for just one page in my app since I need to load data in a lot of different components on the same page (and I need to access $user store). I am using supabase for authentication. The $user store is undefined when I am trying to access it, so I decided to go with SSR. But the routing is broken now.

src/hooks.ts

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    const response = await resolve(event, {
        ssr: event.url.pathname == '/app' ? false : true
        // ssr: !event.url.pathname.startsWith('/app')
        // transformPage: ({ html }) => html.replace('old', 'new')
    });

    return response;
}
```

Links and goto function are not working on the /app endpoint

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with one of the components I was using: recursion in tandem with async/await. I removed that code and the routing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Data loading can be handled server-side by exporting a load function at page level : https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading